# Symfony2 Bootstrap.php.cache

Tags: symfony

I'm developing in **Ubuntu 14** and I get the following error when creating a databaes:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

This is the error output:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/jesse/playground/www/symfony/htdocs/app/bootstrap.php.cache): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
/home/jesse/playground/www/symfony/htdocs/app/console on line 10
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 
'/home/jesse/playground/www/symfony/htdocs/app/bootstrap.php.cache'    
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in   
/home/jesse/playground/www/symfony/htdocs/app/console on line 10
```

**What Ive Tried**

- Running this in Vagrant
- Running this Locally

This is one among several problem running Symfony2 under Ubuntu, the other forcing you to implement `umask(0000)` otherwise you have to get `chmod +a` permissions for `log` and `cache` folders, this seems like a bit of a hassle for something seemingly simple.

Does anyone know what to work around this error?

Comment: As for the umask issue: This goes for any web application, where the local user (i.e. the developer) has a different account than the web server user.

Comment: Thanks for that valuable information lxg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
php /home/jesse/playground/www/symfony/htdocs/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

Comment: However, you seem to have missed a step when setting up your SF2 application, because this file should have been automatically generated during the process.

Comment: I installed via composer as per the instructions, and removed the /cache and /logs folder -- I'm not sure what I did wrong :)

Comment: I also had to `service nginx restart` and `service php-fpm restart` on the server.